# Displaying responsive text in multiple columns and rows in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

In the process of learning basic ReactJS I am trying to create the following layout but I have not been successful in finding solution which leads me to this particular layout which when open on a desktop will look as following (but since it is responsive it will hopefully readjust to screen):

[image]

This is the code I am trying but not sure how to take it to a `responsive` layout I desire.

```
import React from 'react';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div> I am the header</div>
  )
}

   // each footer is 50% wide
function Footer1() {
  return (
    <div> I am footer 1</div>
  )
}

function Footer2() {
  return (
    <div> I am footer 2</div>
  )
}

// left col has with 84%
function LeftCol() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>col1 width 84%</div>
        <div>col1 row1</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

function RightCol() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>col2 width 16%</div>
        <div>col2 row1</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <LeftCol />
      <RightCol />
      <Footer1 />
      <Footer2 />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Edit:
I am trying to achieve this using minimal html and CSS but through ReactJS and Material UI as learning exercise.

Comment: Please show your css code as well

Comment: Or just link a codepen

Comment: I am going to look into codepen. I am new to react but I have removed the CSS calls from my code as they were not necessary

Comment: Welcome to react!! Are you familiar with html, css, or JavaScript?

Comment: Yes right now everything I know are blocks of knowledge so I am trying to combine them together through simple projects.

Comment: I would suggest mastering HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, then move onto react

Comment: Thanks for advice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you.

See if that works for you:

**NOTE:** This is a very basic integration between React and CSS. If you don't have any experience with CSS I suggest you do the [W3Schools CSS course](https://www.w3schools.com/css/). Once you get it done, I suggest you to look into [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics) which, in my opinion is a much nicer way to handle CSS in React components. Also a priority to learn [React basics](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) in the official documentation and other tutorials.

**SNIPPET:**

```js
function Header() {
  return(
    <div className="header">I am Header</div>
  );
}

function Main() {
  return(
    <div className="main">
      <LeftCol/>
      <RightCol/>
    </div>
  );
}

function LeftCol() { 
  return (
    <div className="leftCol">
      <div>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function RightCol() { 
  return (
    <div className="rightCol">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Footer() {
  return(
    <div className="footer">I am Footer</div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Main/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;                 
  height: 80px;                
  display: flex;               
  align-items: center;         
  justify-content: center;     
  font-weight: bold;           
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 200px;*/
  display: flex;
  
}

.leftCol {
  flex: 0 0 84%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rightCol {
  flex: 0 0 16%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}



.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: salmon;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the height of the columns responsive as right now it is set to a fixed number ?

Comment: You don't have to set them at all. They will adjust based on content height if don't set it. I'll edit the example to show you.

Comment: This is a very basic integration between React and CSS. If you don't have any experience with CSS I suggest you do the [W3Schools CSS course](https://www.w3schools.com/css/). Once you get it done, I suggest you to look into [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics) which, in my opinion is a much nicer way to handle CSS in React components. Also a priority to learn [React basics](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).